# In xkb, what is the difference between caps:internal, caps:shift and caps:capslock

Tags: xkb

If I type `cat /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.lst | grep caps:` in a terminal I get

```
  caps:internal        Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
  caps:internal_nocancel Caps Lock uses internal capitalization; Shift does not affect Caps Lock
  caps:shift           Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift "pauses" Caps Lock
  caps:shift_nocancel  Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking; Shift does not affect Caps Lock
  caps:capslock        Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization of alphabetic characters
  caps:shiftlock       Caps Lock toggles Shift Lock (affects all keys)
  caps:swapescape      Swap Esc and Caps Lock
  caps:escape          Make Caps Lock an additional Esc
  caps:escape_shifted_capslock Make Caps Lock an additional Esc, but Shift + Caps Lock is the regular Caps Lock
  caps:backspace       Make Caps Lock an additional Backspace
  caps:super           Make Caps Lock an additional Super
  caps:hyper           Make Caps Lock an additional Hyper
  caps:menu            Make Caps Lock an additional Menu key
  caps:numlock         Make Caps Lock an additional Num Lock
  caps:ctrl_modifier   Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl
  caps:none            Caps Lock is disabled
```

I am unable to tell the difference between "Caps Lock uses internal capitalization", "Caps Lock acts as Shift with locking" (which is not the same as Shift Lock), and "Caps Lock toggles normal capitalization".

Comment: Not sure what it is, but it is described here: 
https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Enhancing.html
With additional note "do not use it directly"

Comment: ["These options are more of historic interest than practical use."](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=44033) was the answer to the same question asked over ten years ago by someone else...